# В приложении на C++ OpenGL после запуска окно открывается, и тут же закрывается. Что делать?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glfw

Программа написана на C++ с использованием OpenGL 3.3 и GLFW. Если использовать закомментированный в функции main код, то всё работает корректно, но если же запускать программу с описанными над main классами, то окно закрывается сразу после запуска. Это очень странно, ведь цикл внутри gameLoop всё равно идёт, это можно понять по тому - что в консоль не выводится сообщение "Engine Finished".
Функция glfwCreateWindow() при этом не возвращает указатель на 0.

Код:

```
#include "glew.h"
#include "glfw3.h"

#include <iostream>

class GLFW
{
public:
    GLFW();
    ~GLFW();
};

class Window
{
public:
    Window(const int width, const int height, const char* title);
    void gameLoop();
    ~Window();
private:
    GLFWwindow* window_ = nullptr;
};

GLFW::GLFW()
{
    glfwInit();
}

GLFW::~GLFW()
{
    glfwTerminate();
}

Window::Window(const int width, const int height, const char* title)
{
    GLFW glfw;

    window_ = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window_);

    glewInit();
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
}

void Window::gameLoop()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window_))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window_);
    }
}

Window::~Window()
{
    glfwDestroyWindow(window_);
}

int main()
{
    Window window(1024, 512, "Synthetic Engine");

    window.gameLoop();

    std::cout << "Engine Finished" << std::endl;

    /*glfwInit();

    GLFWwindow* window_ = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 512, "Synthetic Engine", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window_);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window_)) {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window_);
    }*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: так в конструкторе Window вызывается glfwTerminate когда glfw выходит из области видимости...

Answer (score 0):

так в конструкторе Window вызывается glfwTerminate когда glfw выходит из области видимости...